# Asynchronous logging using Python

Tags: python, logging

I need to log in an asynchronous way. But I am getting an error. How to fix this error.

---

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'asy_log' was never awaited

asy_log("Warning message", "Errorsource1", 'warning')

RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Code :-

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger("asyncio")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
streamhandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
streamhandler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(streamhandler)

filehandler = logging.FileHandler('test3.log')
filehandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(filehandler)

async def asy_log(self, logtext=None, logsource = None, logcriticality= None):
    
    loginfo = logsource + logtext
    await getattr(logger, logcriticality)(loginfo)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asy_log())
    loop.close()


asy_log("Warning message", "Errorsource1", 'warning')
```

Comment: This example code doesn't make sense.  What is `self` here, and why is `asy_log` calling itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this line in your code.

```
await asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

This will create a bit of delay and help the logger work in a better way.

Comment: I already tried "await asyncio.sleep(delay)". But the same error.